# Can't get Moq Setup to not return null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to Setup a Mock call to a the IModelFactory interface that I have.

here is the IModelFactory interface

```
public interface IModelFactory
    {

       MaterialAcceptedModel Create(MaterialAccepted model);                                           
       MaterialAccepted Parse(MaterialAcceptedModel model);        
  }
```

This is the ModelFactory class which implements the IModelFactor interface *(I've only add here the method I'm trying to test, no need to add the implementation of the Create Method)*

```
public class ModelFactory : IModelFactory
    {
        private UrlHelper _urlHelper;
        private IRTWRepository _repo;
        //private IKeysGeneratorService _keysGen;
        private IGeocodeService _geocoder;

        public ModelFactory(HttpRequestMessage request, IRTWRepository repo,IGeocodeService geocoder)
        {
            _urlHelper = new UrlHelper(request);
            _repo = repo;
            _geocoder = geocoder;
        }                


        #region Parses

        public MaterialAccepted Parse(MaterialAcceptedModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.category))
                {
                    var category = _repo.CategoryRepository.Get(model.category);

                    if (category == null) return null;

                    var entry = new MaterialAccepted()
                    {
                        business = model.business,
                        businessService = model.businessService,
                        residential = model.residential,
                        residentialService = model.residentialService,
                        note = model.note,
                        Category = category
                    };
                    return entry;
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

I'm using a BaseAPiController that contains the repo and configuration Interfaces

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
    {
        IRTWRepository _repository;
        IModelFactory _modelFactory;
        IConfiguration _configuration;
        IGeocodeService _geocoder;

        public BaseApiController(IRTWRepository repository,IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected IRTWRepository TheRepository
        {
            get
            {
                return _repository;
            }
        }
        protected IConfiguration TheConfiguration
        {
            get
            {
                return _configuration;
            }
        }

        protected IModelFactory TheModelFactory
        {                              
            get
            {                
                _geocoder = new GeocodeService(_configuration.GetValue("geocodeGoogleApiKey"));

                if (_modelFactory == null)
                {
                    _modelFactory = new ModelFactory(this.Request, _repository,_geocoder);
                }
                return _modelFactory;
            }
        }
```

Here is the action method in the controller I'm trying to test

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/recyclecenters/{rcid}/materials/")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(int rcid, [FromBody]MaterialAcceptedModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model != null)
                {
                    var recycleCenter = TheRepository.RecycleCenterRepository.Get(rcid);

                    if (recycleCenter == null)
                        return NotFound();

                    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                        return BadRequest(ModelState);

                    var entity = TheModelFactory.Parse(model);

                    if (entity == null) return BadRequest("Could not read material accepted in body");


                    if (TheRepository.MaterialAcceptedRepository.Get(recycleCenter.RecycleCenterId, entity.Category.name) != null)
                        return Conflict();

                    recycleCenter.Materials.Add(entity);

                    if (TheRepository.SaveAll())
                    {
                        string locationHeader = Url.Link("Materials", new { rcid = rcid, name = model.category.ToLower() });
                        return Created<MaterialAcceptedModel>(locationHeader, TheModelFactory.Create(entity));
                    }
                    return BadRequest("Could not save to the database");
                }
                return BadRequest();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

This is the line that returns null even though I mocked it up on my test method

```
  var entity = TheModelFactory.Parse(model);
```

and this one is my TestClass

```
namespace API.Tests.Web
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MaterialsControllerTest
    {        
        private Mock<IRTWRepository> repository;
        private Mock<IModelFactory> factory;
        private Mock<IConfiguration> configuration;
        private Mock<IRTWAPIIdentityService> identityService;
        private MaterialsController controller;

        RecycleCenter recycleCenter;        

        private MaterialAccepted CreateMaterial()
        {
            return new MaterialAccepted()
            {
                business = true,
                businessService = EnumRecycleCenterService.Dropoff,
                residential = false,
                residentialService = EnumRecycleCenterService.Pickup,
                note = "this a note",
                Category = new Category()
                {
                    name = "Books"
                }
            };
        }

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            repository = new Mock<IRTWRepository>();
            factory = new Mock<IModelFactory>();
            configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            identityService = new Mock<IRTWAPIIdentityService>();
            controller = new MaterialsController(repository.Object,configuration.Object);
            controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();            
            recycleCenter = new RecycleCenter(){RecycleCenterId = 1};            
        }



        [TestMethod]
        public void Post_ShouldReturnConflictIfTheRecycleCenterAlreadyTakesMaterial()
        {

            //arrange
            repository.Setup(r => r.RecycleCenterRepository.Get(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => recycleCenter);
            factory.Setup(f => f.Parse(new MaterialAcceptedModel())).Returns(() => new MaterialAccepted());
            configuration.Setup(c => c.GetValue(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => "APIKEY");

            repository.Setup(r => r.MaterialAcceptedRepository.Get(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(() => null);       

            //act
            var actionResult = controller.Post(It.IsAny<int>(),new MaterialAcceptedModel());

            //assert
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(actionResult, typeof(ConflictResult));
        }

    }
}
```

This is the line that's not working because it always return null instead of a new instance of MaterialAccepted

```
 factory.Setup(f => f.Parse(new MaterialAcceptedModel())).Returns(() => new MaterialAccepted());
```

I tried f.Parse(It.IsAny()) but still doesn't work.

**To clarify**

the above line of code is returning null because is not mocking the f.Parse() call, instead is executing it and returning null because the if condition I have on that method

Anyone could explain why the Setup is not working?

Comment: The `Setup` you have doesn't work because the instance of `MaterialAcceptedModel` doesn't match between the `Setup` and the call.  You can get around this by using `It.IsAny` as described in my answer.  This can be proved by testing `Assert.IsNotNull(factory.Object.Parse(1, new MaterialAcceptedModel());` within the test method.  However, as I have also explained in my answer, you have a deeper problem since the code you have will not currently make use of the Mock you are creating.  To get around that you need to change the code as suggested, or use profiler based mocking, such as TypeMock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting up your Mock using It.IsAny will work:

```
factory.Setup(f => f.Parse(It.IsAny<MaterialAcceptedModel>()))
       .Returns(() => new MaterialAccepted());
```

However, as has been said by @Macilquham, I can't see where your are passing the Mock to your controller in the supplied code so that it is used by the production code.

If you don't call the method on your Mock object, which you don't, you're currently calling the method on the instance of the real object created by your base class, then it doesn't matter how you set up your mock it's not going to work.  If you are able to change your base class, then doing something like this would allow you to work around your problem:

```
// Add defaulted parameter to base class to allow modelFactory creation
// to be overridden/injected (this will prevent the current default behaviour
// when fetching the factory, if a non-null is passed in)
public BaseApiController(IRTWRepository repository,IConfiguration configuration, 
                         IModelFactory modelFactory = null)
{
    _modelFactory = modelFactory;
}
```

Modify your sut constructor to allow you to supply a modelFactory (again, default it to null), then amend your test as appropriate:

```
controller = new MaterialsController(repository.Object,configuration.Object,
                                     factory.Object);
```

Comment: I tried  like that and it's still not working, I added more code in my question to help to debug my issue, right now the factory.Parse is returning null because it reaches the method on the ModelFactory implementation and returns null as expected but I'm trying to mock that call to returns what I want instead of executing that function

Comment: I'm honestly not passing the IModelFactory into the controller becuase the ModelFactory implementation needs 2 parameters and I don't know how to inject a valid HttpRequestMessage variable ( I use this to generate links for my api answers), any idea how to inject it?

Comment: @JGEstevez As an aside, it's weird that calling get on `TheModelFactory` property of the base class always creates and fetches the value for `_geocoder`, but conditionally creates the value `_modelFactory`

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be injecting in the `IModelFactory` into the controller. You need to make sure that your production code is using the Mock you are setting up in the test.

Comment: Please don't use the answers section for comments.

Comment: Hi Gert, I dont have enough reputation to add comments to other peoples posts.

Comment: @Macilquham Your question could just as easily been phrased as an answer, as per edit.

Comment: @Macilquham  please see the coments I made on forsvarir answers , basically I don't know how to inject a valid HttpRequestMessage variable into the Modelfactory constructor

Answer (score -2):

Mock cannot return null directly. 
The trick is just to create a null object. 
Assuming the object returned is of type **class Material**:

```
    Material nullMaterial = null;
    ...
    repository.Setup(r => r.MaterialAcceptedRepository
      .Get(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
      .Returns(nullMaterial);
```

This should solve your problem

Comment: Whilst this is an interesting approach, it's achieving the opposite of what the OP is requesting.  They are saying that calling the `Parse` method on their factory returns null, which is NOT what they want, they want it to return an object.  As an aside, returning null is the default behaviour on Mocks that haven't been setup, so just not creating a Setup for the method would appear to achieve the same thing as your solution.

Comment: I'm not having problem mocking the repository function, is with the ModelFactory.Parse() where my problem is